# SQL - Add row based on column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a SQLquery that outputs a table like this that has the 5 rows (Cond, Drill 3, Drill 2, Drill 1, Drill 4)

Link sample table.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/950d50/2

I want to create a new query that takes the above queried table and adds a new row where the Task is called DRILL. The DSU and PAD remain the same as they are repeats. But the Start finish should equal the Start Date of Drill 3 (6/17/22) and the Finish date should equal the finish of Drill 4 (11/23/22). How could I code this in SQL so the output is as follows:*

| Task | DSU | Start | Finish | Pad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cond | LS | 6/10/22 | 6/18/22 | PD1 |
| Drill 3 | LS | 7/25/22 | 11/10/22 | PD1 |
| Drill 2 | LS | 7/29/22 | 11/19/22 | PD1 |
| Drill 1 | LS | 6/17/22 | 6/17/22 | PD1 |
| Drill 4 | LS | 11/20/22 | 11/23/22 | PD1 |
| DRILL | LS | 6/17/22 | 11/23/22 | PD1 |

Comment: it would make more sense to do it in your last query. you should post the table you have before the one you posted.

Comment: The table original table I have is exactly like the one posted above except it doesn't have the the last row in it where the Task is DRILL.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table1
UNION
select 'DRILL', pad, dsu, Min(Start), Max(Finish) from table1
GROUP BY pad, dsu
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e2a8ea/6

Comment: That was easy enough.....would this work if the original table has multiple categories of Pads? For example let's say I have in the table another Pad called PD2 with the multiple tasks. I would want to create a new calculated row for DRILL task for both PD1 and PD2 using the same conditions for the dates. 
How could I code that. Assuming the real table I'm working on has multiple pads so in essence I would need to add multiple new rows called DRILL for each PAD. 

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e2a8ea/1

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update, this code however does not produce the desired result. The DRILL start date should be based on each Pads Drill 3 start date (PD1 7/25/22, PD2 8/13/22). 
The DRILL finish date should be based on each Pads Drill 4 finish date (PD1 11/23/22, PD2 12/26/22). Is there a way to use where clause to populate the start and finish dates based on these criteria?